# Floating floor invisible transition

Tags: transition

Can caulk or similar be used to create invisible transition between floating wood flooring and vinyl floor tiling - the floor under the tiling has been built up to match level of floating wood floor) Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not supposed to secure a floating floor in any fashion, and caulking an edge may just do that. If it is a small section of floor, like a small 3X5 ft. powder room, you may get by, (not that I would put a floating floor in a powder room, this is just for example) but a larger floor, you need to use the transition or cap strip made for the laminate floor.